# How to parse json response from API in apex?

Tags: apex, json

I am calling an API from the apex, giving me the following response.

```
    {
    "status": {
        "error": "no",
        "message": "Successfully updated subscriber"
    },
    "result": {
        "method": "email",
        "_id": "62b1b4d3ca04161d9baf811b",
        "address": "sample.23@gmail.com",
        "meth": "email",
        "statuspage": "62600f07f69a9104dcf7e33e",
        "__v": 0,
        "granular": [
            "62600f07f69a9104dcf7e34e_62600f07f69a9104dcf7e34d",
            "62600f07f69a9104dcf7e34e_627bc9811f8e58052d83ed23",
            "62600f07f69a9104dcf7e34e_627bc98a900216053283ceed",
            "62600f07f69a9104dcf7e34e_627bc9a1772026053b778ef8",
            "62600f07f69a9104dcf7e34e_627bc9aaf4dbda05353fa89b",
            "62600f07f69a9104dcf7e34e_627bc9b372a94b052e01b3f3",
            "62600f07f69a9104dcf7e34e_627bcabc69914405344e7a1a"
        ],
        "active": true,
        "join_date": "2022-06-21T12:08:51.817Z"
    }
}
```

How can I parse it so I can use the granular as a list of strings?

Comment: Did you check this https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/. Apart from this you need to replace non apex keywords `__v` and  `_id` from response string.

Answer (score 0):

You can user `JSON.deserializeUntyped()` to deserialize JSON into Apex collections of primitive values. This will convert JSON into an Object value.

So if you want to get granular List then you can use get method like this:

```
Map<String, Object> meta = (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonString);
Map<String,object> getResult = (Map<String,object>) meta.get('result');
List<Object> granularList = (List<Object>) getResult.get('granular');
```

Here granularList will have all the data that you want. And if you want the granular List as `List<String>` then you can convert it like this:

```
List<string> granularStringList = new List<string> ();
for(Object granularListObj: granularList){
   granularStringList.add(String.valueOf(granularListObj));
}
```